# Is there any way to create a trigger for a private function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Doing something like this:

```
function triggerPrivateThing() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('privateThing_').timeBased().after(10).create();
}
```

Strangely results in a trigger being set for doGet() instead of privateThing_().

Answer (score 3):

You can create another method that only calls the private method and setup a trigger against that method.

```
funciton publicM() {
 privateM_();
}
function privateM_() {
 // Code
}
function triggerPrivateThing() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('publicM').timeBased().after(10).create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, at some point between when this question was posted and now, that is has become possible to programmatically create a trigger for a private function in exactly the same way as was outlined in the original question.

```
function triggerPrivateThing() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('privateThing_').timeBased().everyMinutes(10).create();
}
```

It is perhaps worth noting that you still cannot create a trigger for a private function using the GUI in the script editor, however.